# saving null values in database

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to create an event using the code below in java. However after I give it the input needed I check the database to find all of the fields containing null values. what should I do? Thank you in advance.

```
public void CreateEvent(User U){

    try{
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String d;
        //getting inputfrom the user
        System.out.print("Event Name \n");
        d = inFromUser.readLine();
        EventName = d;

        System.out.println("Kindly Provide the start date(Format dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm)");
        //parsing date from user using SimpleDateFormat
        date = sdf.parse(inFromUser.readLine());
        startDate = date.toString();


        System.out.println("Kindly Provide the end date(Format dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm)");
        date = sdf.parse(inFromUser.readLine());
        d = date.toString();
        endDate = d;


        System.out.println("Where is the event:");
        d = inFromUser.readLine();
        Location= d ;

        System.out.println("Description");
        d = inFromUser.readLine();
        Description= d;

        //Get creator UserName
        Creator = U.FullName;

        MyJDBC.Insert(TableName, Fields, Values);


    }
    catch (IOException ex) {//catch the exception

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

values is this

```
String Values= "'"+EventName+"','"+Location +"','"+Description+"','"+startDate+"','"+endDate+"','"+Creator+"'";
```

this is JDBC insert method

```
public void Insert(String TableName,String Fields, String Values){

   try {

       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
       stmt = conn.createStatement();

       String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TableName+ " (" +Fields+ ") VALUES ("+ Values+ ")" ;
       stmt.execute(sql); 
       System.out.println("Successfully inserted record into database");
       stmt.close();
   }
   catch(SQLException se){
           se.printStackTrace();

   }
```

}

Comment: show us your code for `MyJDBC.Insert(TableName, Fields, Values);`
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code sample is not complete. Yet, what can be seen, is that you collect some variables like `EventName` and `Location` and later on you send `values` to the insert method, but that values is never filled.

Your updated question proves that: String in Java is immutable, you cannot change it after creation. Values will not be evaluated again, after the assignment has been done.
At the time you assign it, all variables used to fill it are null.

To solve your problem now, assign values right before you call the insert-method.
To improve your program, write a class DAO with a method `saveEvent()` that takes an `EventVO` as parameter. 
The `EventVO` contains all the collected values as properties.
The save method will create the sql neccessary to insert or update the event.

Also: The java language has the convention, that variables name are lower case, you should stick to that.

Comment: i edited the question and now it has what values contain. i am new to java so i am not familiar with the conventions. i will keep that in mind and stick to the conventions.